# Seaborn tutorial run without errors but no plots appear

Tags: python, matplotlib, freetype

I am running the seaborn tutorial from the seaborn site, and I don't see any plots. I am running this in idle, and I see python launch, but no graphs appear. Tutorial code included below for reference

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import stats
    sns.set(color_codes=True)
    x = np.random.normal(size=100)
    sns.distplot(x);
```

Comment: Have you tried `plt.show()`? although you seem to be plotting using `sns`, I assume they're using `matplotlib` as well for the purpose of plotting? Generally, you should list what you've tried. A quick google search yields some pretty simple solutions to try.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `plt.show()` and it will pop up

Comment: I have always wondered why it works that way. Do you have an idea?

Comment: wow thanks so much I was losing my mind trying to figure out what my problem was